# Converting View to Byte Array to Print

Tags: java, android, printing, arrays

I have a fragment that outputs plain text to the screen for viewing tickets.  I am working on implementing a print function to print the content to a receipt printer (Star Micronics SM-T300i).  I have the SDK installed and working, but I'm just not connecting the dots on how to do this.  All the examples seem to be converting things into bitmaps from byte arrays, etc.  This is my first printing app so I'm just not familiar with the process.  I want to print the same XML file I use to view on the screen to the printer in text mode so it uses the printers native fonts.  Am I on the wrong track?  Thank you.

Comment: you don't need to convert the whole view to `byte[]` just the content, unless you want to print it as image, i think `view.getText().toString().getBytes();` should be good for you

Comment: Thanks, Yazan, but I'm not able to get that to work.  view won't accept getText() on it.

Comment: you need to cast it, how did you set text on the view at first place?
if it's a textView then cast the view and use getText()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using an ArrayList for each line item to print.  It is a receipt so there's no special formatted.  For example:

```
list.add(("Ticket NO: " + data.get("ticketNo") + "\n").getBytes());
```

I then sent the entire list to the printer SDK command to print. Trying to print what the user sees on the screen was not necessary and easier to just output the information like this.